# preventDefault() not working on('submit')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get my on('submit') event handler to prevent submitting the form using event.preventDefault();

```
 $("section.shopping-cart").on('submit','form.adjustform input[type="submit"]', function(event)     {   

      // code

      event.preventDefault();
 })
```

i had had it working using on('click') and using return false. Altho i've read that the above method is the correct way of doing it..

Thanks,
Cam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the delegating form of `on`, with the selector selecting something other than a form element:

```
// Here ------------------------------------------------v
$("section.shopping-cart").on('submit','form.adjustform input[type="submit"]', ...
```

The `submit` event occurs on `form` elements (at least, the one you can usefully cancel does). Specify a *form* element:

```
$("section.shopping-cart").on('submit','form.adjustform', ...
```

Here's an example of it **not** working because the selector selects non-form elements:

[Example](http://jsbin.com/oxireb/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/oxireb/2/edit)

And here's the corrected example working correctly:

[Example](http://jsbin.com/oxireb/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/oxireb/1/edit)

(**Note**: The forms open in new windows, just to avoid taking you away from the code.)

Comment: brillant, thanks! i hadn't considered the relationship between the event and the selector within on(). make sense

Comment: My selector selects a form element by its ID, and yet it cannot prevent the form from submitting.  I think there's a bug in jQuery with delegated events.  A delegated form submit event just cannot be cancelled, while directly bound handler can stop it just fine.  By the time a delegated handler runs, the form has already posted to the server, so there's no chance to even call preventDefault.

Comment: @Triynko: No, that's not true. [`select` isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips), and neither is jQuery's event delegation: http://output.jsbin.com/suwetujoyo A delegated event's default *can* be prevented, because it isn't performed until and unless the event has finished bubbling and it remains unprevented.

Answer (score 3):

The submit event happens on the form, not on the submit button.

Either bind the event to the form:

```
$("section.shopping-cart").on('submit','form.adjustform', function(event)     {
```

or bind the click event of the submit button:

```
$("section.shopping-cart").on('click','form.adjustform input[type="submit"]', function(event)     {
```

(However, some browsers also allows pressing enter to submit the form, in which case it would not trigger the click event.)

Comment: Moreover, cancelling the `click` event of a `submit` button does not reliably prevent submission of the form.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: When doesn't that prevent submission of the form?

Comment: @ Guffa: Hey, I didn't write the event handling in browsers. :-) Hooking and preventing the click on submit buttons didn't work reliably cross-browser, I remember running into this as an issue years ago. It certainly *should* work. It may well do now, but it didn't used to.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Stopping the click event should reliably also stop the sumission. Was it perhaps the ability to submit the button without using the button (which I mentioned in the answer) that was the problem?

Comment: @ Guffa: I don't think so, no; that's *another* reason not to use `click` for this, of course, but I'm pretty sure we were seeing it with some browsers even when one did actually click the button. And again: I completely agree it **should** stop the submission, I'm talking about a bug I saw in at least one major browser, a few years back. (Doesn't seem to be IE, I just checked IE6 and it was fine.)

Comment: Pressing enter is not a click, and yet it submits a form.  Meanwhile, the delegated event cannot seem to prevent the form submission.